# Find closest date to month end for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, max

In a table I have a field containing date in the form of dd/mm/yyyy:

```
TBL_Metrics:
DATE | MetricValue
03/02/2015 | 99.1%
04/02/2015 | 97.3%
03/03/2015 | 94.5%
29/03/2015 | 93.6%
07/04/2015 | 43.9%
30/04/2015 | 94.2%
...
```

I would like to build a sql code which would look into all these dates and:

1. Detect the month of the date
2. within each month, look for the date which is the closest to month end
   (in the very short example above, for february the closest date to month end is 04/02/2015)
3. Re-use the closest dates to month end in a select query:

> Select TBL_Metrics.Date, TBL_Metrics.MetricValue
>        FROM TBL_Metrics
>        WHERE TBL_Metrics.Date in ('04/02/2015','29/03/2015','30/04/2015')

I have no clue how to do this in sql, for the moment I do it in VBA but it forces me to have a dummy spreadsheet with the database connexion, to first retrieve all dates, then loop on all dates to find the closest date to month end and then I can build my query to use in another spreqdsheet, which is messy.

To give you an idea here is how I found the closest date to month end in vba:

```
dat1month = January
dat2month = February
dat3month = March
For i = 2 To LR
    If MonthName(Month(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3))) = dat1month Then
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) > Dat1max Then
            Dat1max = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3)
        End If
    ElseIf MonthName(Month(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3))) = dat2month Then
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) > Dat2max Then
            Dat2max = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3)
        End If
    ElseIf MonthName(Month(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3))) = dat3month Then
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) > Dat3max Then
            Dat3max = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3)
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

I hope somebody can help!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant table's DDL, some sample data (preferably as DML statements) and desired output.

Comment: Hi Zohar, Apologies, hopefully it's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [cte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to add a [row number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) column to help find the closest day to the end of the month and then query that cte:

```
;With cte as
(
  SELECT Date, MetricValue, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date) ORDER BY Day(Date) DESC) rn
  FROM TBL_Metrics
)

SELECT Date, MetricValue
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, I think you can use the SQL ranking function ROW_NUMBER to help out, like this...

```
SELECT  Date ,
        MetricValue
FROM    (
            SELECT  Date ,
                    MetricValue ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY (YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date) ORDER BY Date DESC)
            FROM    TBL_Metrics
        ) x
```